# Number function returning 0

Tags: javascript, nan

For example, this piece of code:

```
Number("") + Number("")
```

I expect to return "" (aka nothing)
so I created this function

```
    function addthese(x, y){
        if (x != ""){
            asdf = Number(x) + Number(y)
            return  Number(asdf)
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
```

But for some reason this function returns `NaN`
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What input and output are you expecting? Running `addthese("", "")` already returns `""`

Comment: beacuase when don't pass the argument, it will become undefined and Number(undefined) equals to `NaN`

Comment: You are just checking `X` for `""`, what about `Y`, and other values like `undefined` or `abc`? If `Number(Y)` is `NaN` then everything will be `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, you might be calling the function without passing in parameters. I did some quick tests and that's the only way i managed to reproduce the "NaN" returning.

If that's the case, the function will "parse" an undefined value, which is not possible and you'll get that ugly NaN you got.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to cache all cases related to undefined, null, false or "" please use the following code:

```
function addthese(x, y){
    return isNaN(x) || isNaN(y) ? "" :  Number(x) + Number(y)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `Number` function can convert an empty string to 0, for any non-number string, it doesn't have a clue. So, `NaN` is returned.

```js
console.log(Number(""));
console.log(Number(undefined));
console.log(Number("foo"));
```